# Cointegration of two $I(0)$ plus $T$

Tags: cointegration

I have two series that are $I(0)+T$, and I wonder if I can consider cointegration relationship between them. $x$ is $I(0)+T$ and $y$ is $I(0)+T$. The Johansen test tells that $x$ and $y$ are cointegrated. The regression residuals are stationary.

Is my procedure correct?

Comment: What is "+T"? Trend?

Answer (score 1):

Citing from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cointegration):

> If two or more series are individually integrated (in the time series sense) but some linear combination of them has a lower order of integration, then the series are said to be cointegrated.

Similar definitions can be found also in time series textbooks, e.g. Lutkepohl "New Introduction to Multiple Time Series Analysis" (2005) Chapter 6.

If the individual series are I(0), they are not integrated. A *deterministic* trend (like a linear time trend) will *not* do; I(0) plus a time trend does not constitute an integrated time series. You would need a *stochastic* trend to get an integrated time series. Thus you *cannot* proceed to cointegration analysis.

What you could do is model the two series in a VAR or VARMA model including an exogenous variable - a linear time trend (if that is what the T stands for in your question).